# dom4j - select node by 2 conditions

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I want to select node element by 2 conditions. For example:

```
<bbb>
    <aaa name="param1">val1</aaa>
    <aaa name="param2">val2</aaa>
    <aaa name="param3">val3</aaa>
</bbb>
```

I want to get element aaa, with attribute name = "param1". What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already parsed the document with Dom4j, then...

```
Document doc = ...
Node node = doc.selectSingleNode("//aaa[@name='param1']");
```

... should work. The `node` variable should contain your desired element.